# Memory leak when using IShellItem2.GetString()

Tags: c++, shell, winapi, memory-leaks

I'm using the following code to enumerate the contents of the Recyclebin Shell folder and get the file type of each item.
The code gives the expected results but if I call the function in a loop it looks like there's some memory leak when using the IshellItem2 GetString function (see attached screenshot at the end).

- Am I cleaning up everything properly?
- Am I misinterpreting the results?

```cpp
void Test1()
{
    // Get recyclebin ishellitem
    IShellItem* psiRecycleBin;
    if (SUCCEEDED(SHGetKnownFolderItem(FOLDERID_RecycleBinFolder, KF_FLAG_DEFAULT,
        NULL, IID_PPV_ARGS(&psiRecycleBin))))
    {
        // Get ishellitem contents enumerator
        IEnumShellItems* pesi;
        if (SUCCEEDED(psiRecycleBin->BindToHandler(NULL, BHID_EnumItems, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pesi))))
        {
            IShellItem* psi;
            while (pesi->Next(1, &psi, NULL) == S_OK)
            {
                // Get ishellitem2 from ishellitem
                IShellItem2* psi2;
                if (SUCCEEDED(psi->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&psi2))))
                {
                    // Get the item file type string
                    LPWSTR fileType = NULL;
                    if (SUCCEEDED(psi2->GetString(PKEY_ItemTypeText, &fileType)))
                    {
                        CoTaskMemFree(fileType);
                    }
                    psi2->Release();
                }
                psi->Release();
            }
            pesi->Release();
        }
        psiRecycleBin->Release();
    }
}
```

And I'm calling it in loop like this:

```cpp
#define STRICT_TYPED_ITEMIDS

#include <shlobj.h>
#include <propkey.h>
#include <iostream>

void Test1();

int main()
{
    (void)CoInitialize(NULL);

    std::cout << "Enumerating recyclebin items..\n";

    for (int ii = 0; ii < 5000; ii++)
    {
        Test1();
    }

    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

When debugging this console program in VS in the memory diagnostics window this is what I get:

[image: Visual Studio memory tool]

Thanks for the help

Comment: I reproduce and don't see anything wrong with your code. GetString for this object is merely a shortcut for BindToHandler(BHID_PropertyStore, &ps) + ps.GetValue, etc. It seems that just binding to the property store causes the leak. And I don't reproduce with other folders, like FOLDERID_ProgramFilesX64. You should send to Microsoft.

Comment: I can reproduce this issue and will confirm internally. Thanks for bring this to our attention.

Answer (score 1):

yes, here really exist memory leak, related to `HIDDENRECYCLEBINDATAV2` structure from *shell32.dll*

partial definition of it:

```
struct HIDDENRECYCLEBINDATAV2
{
    //... some mebers
    FILETIME time;
    PWSTR pszLocationBeforeDelete = 0; // !!! not released 
    PWSTR pszLocationInRecycleBin = 0; // !!! not released

    HRESULT Serialize(PBYTE *, PUSHORT);

    static HRESULT Deserialize(
        _In_reads_bytes_opt_(cbStream) const BYTE *pbStream , 
        _In_ USHORT cbStream, 
        _Out_ HIDDENRECYCLEBINDATAV2 ** pphrbd);

    static HRESULT Initialize(HIDDENRECYCLEBINDATAV1 const *, HIDDENRECYCLEBINDATAV2**);

};
```

this structure hold 2 strings - file path from where it deleted ( *pszLocationBeforeDelete* - this is my name, i don't know original) and current file path in Recycle Bin ( *pszLocationInRecycleBin* - again my name)

this names allocated inside `Deserialize` method, by call [`IStream_ReadStrLong`](http://undoc.airesoft.co.uk/shlwapi.dll/IStream_ReadStrLong.php) and must be freed with [`CoTaskMemFree`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-cotaskmemfree). but how i found - `CoTaskMemFree` never called for this two strings.

pseudo code for `Deserialize` :

```
static HRESULT HIDDENRECYCLEBINDATAV2::Deserialize(
    _In_reads_bytes_opt_(cbInit) const BYTE *pbStream , 
    _In_ USHORT cbStream, 
    _Out_ HIDDENRECYCLEBINDATAV2 ** pphrbd)
{
    HRESULT hr = E_FAIL;

    if (HIDDENRECYCLEBINDATAV2 *phrbd = new HIDDENRECYCLEBINDATAV2)
    {
        if (IStream *pStream = SHCreateMemStream(pbStream, cbStream))
        {
            if (0 <= (hr = IStream_ReadStrLong(pStream, &phrbd->pszLocationBeforeDelete)) &&
                0 <= (hr = IStream_ReadStrLong(pStream, &phrbd->pszLocationInRecycleBin)))
            {
                *pphrbd = phrbd, phrbd = 0;
            }

            pStream->Release();
        }

        CoTaskMemFree(phrbd); // !! error, need delete phrbd
    }
    
    return hr;
}
```

and it called from `CBitBucket::_ValidateItem` :

```
HRESULT InitDeletedItem(PCWSTR pszLocationBeforeDelete, PCWSTR pszLocationBeforeDelete, DELETEDITEM *);

static HRESULT CBitBucket::_ValidateItem(_ITEMIDLIST_RELATIVE const *, DELETEDITEM ** ppdi)
{
    HIDDENRECYCLEBINDATAV2 * phrbd;
    if (0 <= HIDDENRECYCLEBINDATAV2::Deserialize(pbStream, cbStream, &phrbd))
    {
        if (DELETEDITEM * pdi = new DELETEDITEM)
        {
            if (0 <= InitDeletedItem( phrbd->pszLocationBeforeDelete,
                phrbd->pszLocationInRecycleBin, pdi))
            {
                *ppdi = pdi, pdi = 0;
            }

            if (pdi) delete pdi;
        }

        CoTaskMemFree(phrbd); // !! error, need delete phrbd
    }
}
```

in both functions - memory for `HIDDENRECYCLEBINDATAV2` simply released with `CoTaskMemFree` api, but memory for strings inside this structure not released. i think need add

```
   HIDDENRECYCLEBINDATAV2::~HIDDENRECYCLEBINDATAV2()
   {
      CoTaskMemFree(pszLocationInRecycleBin);
      CoTaskMemFree(pszLocationBeforeDelete);
   }
```

to this structure and call `delete` instead `CoTaskMemFree`

---

how possible found this ? i hook `RtlAllocateHeap` and `RtlFreeHeap` before **second** call to `Test1()` (important do this not on first call, because during first call may be additional libs load, some differed initialization, etc.. - all this can distort the real result)and log all alloc/free calls in current thread. also i replace `while (pesi->Next..`) to `if (pesi->Next..)` (usually one iteration is enough ). and i found that count of alloc on 2 more than count of free. so i easy found from where this 2 allocations- inside `IStream_ReadStrLong`. then i set breakpoint here and easy view from where this called :

```
CBitBucket::_ValidateItem
  HIDDENRECYCLEBINDATAV2::Deserialize
    IStream_ReadStrLong
      CoTaskMemAlloc
```

partial demo code for log:

```
struct AI 
{
    PVOID BaseAddress;
    PVOID From;
    ULONG Size;
    ULONG Flags;
};

struct TID 
{
    AI *pi;
    ULONG nAlloc, nFree, nCells, MaxAllocDelta;
    BOOL bNotLog;

    TID()
    {
        RtlZeroMemory(this, sizeof(*this));
    }
};

BOOLEAN NTAPI hook_RtlFreeHeap(PVOID HeapHandle, ULONG Flags, PVOID BaseAddress )
{
    TID* p = RTL_FRAME<TID>::get();

    if (!p || p->bNotLog)
    {
        return RtlFreeHeap(HeapHandle, Flags, BaseAddress) != 0;
    }

    p->bNotLog = TRUE;

    if (!RtlFreeHeap(HeapHandle, Flags, BaseAddress))
    {
        __debugbreak();
    }

    if (BaseAddress)
    {
        AI* pi = p->pi;
        ULONG n = p->nCells;
        do 
        {
            if (pi->BaseAddress == BaseAddress)
            {
                pi->BaseAddress = 0;
                p->nFree++;
                break;
            }
        } while (pi++, --n);

        if (!n)
        {
            __debugbreak();
        }
    }

    p->bNotLog = FALSE;

    return TRUE;
}

PVOID NTAPI hook_RtlAllocateHeap( PVOID HeapHandle, ULONG Flags, SIZE_T Size )
{
    TID* p = RTL_FRAME<TID>::get();

    if (!p || p->bNotLog)
    {
        return RtlAllocateHeap(HeapHandle, Flags, Size);
    }

    p->bNotLog = TRUE;

    if (PVOID BaseAddress = RtlAllocateHeap(HeapHandle, Flags, Size))
    {
        AI* pi = p->pi;
        ULONG n = p->nCells;
        do 
        {
            if (!pi->BaseAddress)
            {
                pi->BaseAddress = BaseAddress;
                pi->From = _ReturnAddress();
                pi->Size = (ULONG)Size;
                pi->Flags = Flags;
                p->nAlloc++;

                ULONG k = p->nAlloc - p->nFree;
                if (k > p->MaxAllocDelta)
                {
                    p->MaxAllocDelta = k;
                }
                break;
            }
        } while (pi++, --n);

        if (!n)
        {
            __debugbreak();
        }

        p->bNotLog = FALSE;

        return BaseAddress;
    }

    return 0;
}

void TestEx()
{
    enum { cell_count = 0x1000 };
    if (AI* pi = new AI[cell_count])
    {
        Test1();// first call
        // hook RtlAllocateHeap + RtlFreeHeap
        {
            RtlZeroMemory(pi, cell_count * sizeof(AI));
            RTL_FRAME<TID> f;
            f.pi = pi;
            f.nCells = cell_count;

            Test1();// second call

            DbgPrint("%x(%x) %x\n", f.nAlloc, f.nFree, f.MaxAllocDelta);

            if (f.nAlloc - f.nFree)
            {
                ULONG n = cell_count;
                AI* qi = pi;
                do 
                {
                    if (qi->BaseAddress)
                    {
                        DbgPrint("%p> %x %x\n", qi->From, qi->Size, qi->Flags);
                    }
                } while (qi++, --n);
            }
        }
        delete [] pi;
    }
}
```